# How to keep the required files when refresh web page

Tags: jquery, pjax

I have a project requirement for the page to refresh but retain the contents of another, but I'm not sure why my current implementation isn't working.

I have 3 files as follows:

test6.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="jquery.pjax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php require_once "test10.php"?>
    <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
        Go to <a href="test9.php">next page</a>.
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

test10.php

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

test9.php

```
<h1>this is test9</h1>
```

How do I keep the content of test10 when I refresh test9?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean, can you elaborate?  What specifically are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441820/cant-get-basic-pjax-example-to-work)

Comment: @David I required test10.php to test6.php. Then with pjax i change the content of #pjax-container with tes9.php's content. So i will have content of test10.php on top and test9.php at the bottom. But when i press F5 content of test10.php loss. So i what i want is how to keep test10.php content when i refresh the page.